# Stream android screen

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to fallow [Truiton ScreenCapture](https://github.com/Truiton/ScreenCapture) example, in order to record the device screen using [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html)

When saving the recording localy it works

```
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    String localFilePath = getLocalFilePath();
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(localFilePath);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

How ever when changing to work with FileDescriptor it's not

```
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    String hostname = "10.26.100.18";
    int port = 2007;
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
    ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
    LocalServerSocket localServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(localServerSocket.getFileDescriptor());

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

If not using the LocalServerSocket, then `mMediaRecorder.prepare()` throw exception, now that I am using it, get exception in the below method in `mMediaRecorder.getSurface()`

```
private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
    return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
            DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null
            /*Handler*/);
}
```

The exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to get surface
   at android.media.MediaRecorder.getSurface(Native Method)
   at com.truiton.screencapture.MainActivity$override.createVirtualDisplay(MainActivity.java:172)
   at com.truiton.screencapture.MainActivity$override.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:133)
   at com.truiton.screencapture.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
   at com.truiton.screencapture.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:0)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my Java server, I get socket after `mMediaRecorder.prepare()` is called and it stuck on `inputStream.read` as eccpected. The exception in Android happands when I call `mMediaRecorder.start()`

```
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2007);
        while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            File videoFile = createEmptyVideoFile();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            int length = inputStream.read(buffer);
            while (length != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                length = inputStream.read(buffer);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use LocalServerSocket, below is what partially worked for me, I have a MediaStreamer class which extends MediaRecorder.

```
public class MediaStreamer extends MediaRecorder {

    private LocalServerSocket localServerSocket = null;
    private LocalSocket receiver, sender = null;

    public void prepare() throws IllegalStateException,IOException {

        receiver = new LocalSocket();
        try {
            localServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket("<your_socket_addr>");
            receiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("<your_socket_addr>"));
            receiver.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
            receiver.setSendBufferSize(4096);
            sender = localServerSocket.accept();
            sender.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
            sender.setSendBufferSize(4096); 
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new IOException("Can't create local socket !");
        }

        setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor());

        try {
            super.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            closeSockets();
            throw e;
        }           
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {

        InputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = receiver.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return out;

    }


    public void stop() {
        closeSockets();
        super.stop();
    }

    private void closeSockets() {
        if (localServerSocket !=null) {
            try {
                localServerSocket.close();
                sender.close();
                receiver.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
            localServerSocket = null; 
            sender = null; 
            receiver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**For Recording**

```
video = new MediaStreamer();
video.reset();

video.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
video.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
video.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
video.setVideoFrameRate(VideoConstants.frameRate);
video.setVideoEncodingBitRate(VideoConstants.bitRate*1000);
video.setVideoSize(VideoConstants.resolationX, VideoConstants.resolationY);
video.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

try {
   video.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
video.start();
```

---

**But the main problem is mp4 is not very easy to stream** . The basic problem is that MP4 is not live, streamable format, so even though data is captured via the socket, the crucial file headers which are normally written at the conclusion of an audio or video capture, are missing (because sockets are not seekeable like local files) - hence the unplayable data (And so, why it works fine when saved as local files, is understandable).

There is no easy way to perform post-processing on the data to manually add the file headers. So the solution is either don't use MP4 as the recording format, or, write a packetiser similar to what is used in the [Spydroid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) project

Hope this helps !

Comment: Is my answer not sufficient or any more clarifications required, plz let me know ?

Comment: How to find 'your_socket_addr' in nodejs - easyRTC architecture?

Comment: @AbhinavPuri What format do you recommend to stream?