# Stream android screen with MediaProjection API

Tags: android-mediaprojection

i would like to build an Android application to stream the screen to a Java desktop program, but i don't understand how to get the video to be sent to pc.

The answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524196/stream-android-screen) link suggests to use `LocalSocket` and `LocalServerSocket`: but aren't LocalSockets actually local Unix sockets? They can't send data to another host, can they?

So, how can i use Datagram Sockets to send the video?

Also, the user states that mp4 is not suitable for streaming: is it enough to change Output Format and Video Encoder?